# Drush custom command not found in context of running --root option

Tags: 8, drush

Drush 8. Have the custom module with the custom command.

Call `drush custom-command` works as expected.

Call `drush --root=sites/subsite custom-command` thiggers the error:

`The drush command 'custom-command' could not be found.`

How to call the drush command in the context of the subsite?

Comment: Is the custom module enabled in the sub site?

Comment: Drush 8 on a Drupal 8? Better provide Drush 9 commands from inside your module's src/Commands directory.

Comment: Drush 9 handle that pretty good, but there's no possibility to run the @sites alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a command on a certain instance of a multisite you are supposed to pass the `-l` option. Also be sure that the custom module that provides the custom command is enabled on the multisite instance you are trying to call that command on.

```
$ drush custom-command -l subsite
```